# fetch attibute value of worldnow in rss

Tags: php

I have received feed from url and I am regenerating the feed after making some changes in it So How to fetch value of "wn:size" attribute in php. Structure of feed are in following format:

```
 <rss xmlns:a10="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
 <channel xmlns:wn="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:dc="http://api.worldnow.com/cms" xmlns:media="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
  <item>
  <media:thumbnail wn:size="custom" url="image url"  />
  </item>
  </channel>
 </rss>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get `wn:size` value then you need to `parse` your `rss feed response` as `XML` using `simplexml_load_string` function.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string('your rss feed');
foreach($xml->channel->item as $item) {
    $media = $item->children('media', 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
    echo $media->thumbnail->attributes('wn',true)->size;
}
```