# how to detect value of attibute from worldnow feed in rss

Tags: php

I have received feed from url and I am regenerating the feed after making some changes in it So How to fetch value of "wn:size" attribute in php. Structure of feed are in following format:

```
 <rss xmlns:a10="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
  <channel xmlns:wn="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"      xmlns:dc="http://api.worldnow.com/cms" xmlns:media="http://purl.org   /dc/elements/1.1/">
    <item>
    <media:thumbnail wn:size="custom" url="image url"  />
    </item>
    </channel>
   </rss>
```

Comment: please review the answer the given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35146226/fetch-attibute-value-of-worldnow-in-rss

Comment: @user2181397 i have edited the url